# incorrect time zone set in Ubuntu 12.04 through puppet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and use puppet to change the timezone from UTC to PST when the server comes up. Puppet's timezone recipe which I am using is this:
[Puppet Time Recipe](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Timezone_Patterns)

Things were working fine with Ubuntu 10.04, now we are moving to Ubuntu 12.04 and this Puppet recipe doesn't work.
Reason I figured out is in 10.04 /etc/localtime is a file with contents PST8PDT whereas in 12.04 it is a symlink(because of puppet recipe) and it is linked to SystemV/ but the path of SystemV directory is not correct. When I do a ls -l in /etc

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Oct 18 18:38 localtime -> ../SystemV/PST8PDT
```

But there is no SystemV folder one level up of /etc.
I changed the puppet recipe to this:

```
class timezone::pacific inherits timezone {
file { "/etc/localtime":
    require => Package["tzdata"],
 #   source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific",
    source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/PST8PDT",
```

and it worked and localtime was no longer a link.
Can anyone please help me understand why the puppet recipe which I inherited and was working fine on 10.04 didnt work on 12.04 and why changing  the recipe to the new SystemV destination fixed it .

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit odd.  On my 12.04 VM both `/usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/PST8PDT` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific` are a symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles`.  Either path you used should have resulted in a `/etc/localtime` which was a link to `../America/Los_Angeles`.

Have you considered doing a `links => follow`?  That way puppet would resolve the symlink and copy the contents instead of copying the symlink.

Comment: Hmmm....interesting....On my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS VM, /etc/localtime is a file and not a symlink.  I installed this VM from scratch using the Ubuntu "official" DVD.  The same for the SystemV PST8PDT file.

Comment: @mdpc, right but he is trying to update the localtime with puppet, which I believe will copy a symlink and not follow it.  Since he is pointing at a symlink he is getting a copy of that relative symlink in a place that is broken.

Comment: One more piece of information which might be helpful, I am doing this on Amazon cloud instance and the ami I am using is ami-057bcf6c

Comment: I also noticed that in 12.04 /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific is a link to SystemV/PST8PDT but in 10.04 /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific doent link to any file.

Comment: @Zoredache I tried links=>follow in the puppet recipe with source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific", I noticed that localtime file was not a symlink but had UTC0 as the content.